# How to check if an element in a cell array is unique or repeated

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a <465x1> cell array. For check each element, I want to check whether it is unique or a repeated element.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) for this purpose, it can work on cell arrays too:

```
[U, ic, iu] = unique(C);
```

Where `C` is your cell array. `U` is a new cell array with the same values as `C` but without repetitions. You can then count the occurrences of each value using [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
[U, ic, iu] = unique(C);
count = histc(iu, 1:numel(ic))
```

#### Example

For the sake of the example, let's generate a random cell array of strings first:

```
strings = {'foo'; 'bar'; 'baz'; 'bang'};
C = strings(ceil(numel(strings) * rand(6, 1)))
```

This should generate something like this:

```
C = 
    'bang'
    'baz'
    'foo'
    'bang'
    'bar'
    'foo'
```

Now we count the occurrences of each value in `C`:

```
C = strings(ceil(numel(strings) * rand(6, 1)));
[U, ic, iu] = unique(C);
count = histc(iu, 1:numel(ic))
```

This should result in:

```
U =
   'foo'
   'bar'
   'baz'
   'bang'

count =
    2
    1
    1
    2
```

which means that `'foo'` and `'bang'` are repeated twice, while the rest only once, which is correct.
If you are only interested in the truly unique values, you can do:

```
U(count == 1)
```

Which should return in our example:

```
'bar'
'baz'
```

Note that each element in `count` represents the corresponding value in `U` (not `strings`, they may have a different order).

Comment: Nice explanation, note that you can also find the truly unique values without `find`, by using `U(count==1)`